# How pressure force is doing work on tapered sides in inertial moving frame but not in rest frame?(

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, flow, bernoulli-equation

While trying to understand Bernoulli application in inertial moving frame i tried watching this video https://youtu.be/CT4H3Xt84ZE  but i dont understand few things from 7:04 to 7:42 :  Sir told that pressure force from side of walls in the MNOP section will not to do any work when considered tube frame/ground frame , but i dont understand why ? And how it will do work(pressure from walls) on the tapered section when inertial frame moving with v2 speed ?

Comment: I think you will get more attention and possibly useful answers to your question if it is self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a generic feature of forces in Newtonian mechanics and has nothing specifically to do with Bernoulli or cones. Consider the following generic derivation:

The rate of work done by a force $\vec F$ is given by $P = \vec F \cdot \vec v$ where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the material at the point of application of $\vec F$. If we transform to another frame moving at velocity $\vec u$ with respect to the first frame then the power is given by $$P' = \vec F' \cdot \vec v'$$  $$ P' = \vec F \cdot (\vec v + \vec u)$$  $$P' = \vec F \cdot \vec v + \vec F \cdot \vec u$$  $$P'=P+\vec F \cdot \vec u$$

So, in the original frame since $\vec v=0$ we immediately have $P=0$. But in another frame $P'=P+\vec F \cdot \vec u = \vec F \cdot \vec u$ which may be nonzero.